# Where to set path of an Angular 2 main.js file in an asp.net core app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have the usual `wwwroot/app/main.js` file and using the selector `<my-app>` inside the `index.cshtml` which is the default and is found in `Views/Home` everything loads fine. The main.js is being found under `localhost:5000/app/main.js` but as soon as I use the selector inside another `.cshtml` file under the same `Views/Home` path I get a 404 error and I see that the application is looking for main.js under `localhost:5000/Home/app/main.js`. Apparently is looking for the file in the wrong path.

I tried changing the

```
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

which is found in `_Layout.cshtml` giving it the full path of main.js but it didn't work.

Comment: check this link http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/04/04/aspnetcore-and-angular2-part1.html

Comment: how are you currently setting the path ?

Comment: @Shyju if the `System.import('app')` is how you set up the path then it's the default `app`. I tried thinks like `app/main` and `wwwroot/app/main` but it didn't work.

Comment: @rashfmnb the only relevant I can see is the `app/boot` it uses to set the path.

Comment: Did you add `<base href="/">` in the `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: @traveller I followed [this](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa) but here it is using angular-cli as well . did you use angular-cli ?